# Check array with day object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, api

I have an array of object,

```
DayEffort:[{
    Description: null
    Effort: 2
    EffortDate: "2019-05-20T00:00:00"
    day:Sunday
    Status: "In Progress"
   },       
    { 
    Description: null
    Effort: 1.5
    EffortDate: "2019-05-22T00:00:00"
    Day : Tuesday 
    Status: "In Progress"
    },
    {

    Description: null
    Effort: 1.5
    EffortDate: "2019-05-23T00:00:00"
    Day : Thursday
    Status: "In Progress"

}]
```

which contain day property, if day is sunday, it needs to push on zero index of new array, Monday is on 1st index, if not matching push null value,

Excepted result:

```
NewArray : [
0:{Description: null Effort: 2 EffortDate: "2019-05-20T00:00:00" day:Sunday Status: "In Progress"},
1: null,
2: {Description: null Effort: 2 EffortDate: "2019-05-20T00:00:00" day:Tuesday Status: "In Progress"},
3: null,
4: {Description: null Effort: 2 EffortDate: "2019-05-20T00:00:00" day:Thursday Status: "InProgress"},
5: null,
6: null,
]
```

Tried,

```
var DayArray = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday', 'Saterday'];  
for(var k = 0 ; k < DayArray.length; k++){  
                     for(var m = 0; m < DayEffort.length; m++){                        

                         if(DayArray[k] == DayEffort[m].day){
                             NewArray.push(DayEffort[m]);

                         }
                         else{
                             NewArray.push(null);                                                            
                         }

                     }                      
                 }
```

Please help me,

Comment: Please share any attempt that you have done. Just giving input output format, and asking for help is not a good question

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: @Rajesh, I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this (After fixing your invalid object values and missing commas)

```js
const DayEffort = [{ Description: null, Effort: 2, EffortDate: "2019-05-20T00:00:00", Day: "Sunday", Status: "In Progress" }, { Description: null, Effort: 1.5, EffortDate: "2019-05-22T00:00:00", Day: "Tuesday", Status: "In Progress" }, { Description: null, Effort: 1.5, EffortDate: "2019-05-23T00:00:00", Day: "Thursday", Status: "In Progress" } ];

let NewArray= new Array(7).fill(null);
const DayArray = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

DayEffort.forEach(item => NewArray[DayArray.indexOf(item.Day)] = item);
console.log(NewArray);
```